# Displaying more than 50 legend entries

Tags: matlab, plot, customization, legend, undocumented-behavior

I would like to plot 66 datasets and show their legends. Unfortunately, [according to the MathWorks Support Team](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/362378), MATLAB legends are limited by default to 50 entries.

I tried the workaround they suggested that involves making another axes in the plot, copying the previous data, and then hiding the new axes, but I couldn't get it to work (the new axes only shows 1 additional variable from the 16 that are left), and so I'm stuck.

Are there any other ways to display more than 50 legend entries?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please post your code here, or at least a minimum working example to showcase the error, avoid a dropbox link, as this will likely be lost over time, while we want this site to be helpful for other people that may find this question. If you are mentioning other resources with possible solutions, please post a link to them as well. But anyway, with 50 items, you are likely not going to have anything presentable in the legend key. Maybe consider another way to display the data you want.

Comment: 50 legend items is 45 too many.

Comment: @CrisLuengo For "static" figures I completely agree. However, this might be a perfectly reasonable use case when investigating the plot [interactively](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotbrowser.html) ([example](https://imgur.com/a/TRFQwcL)).

Comment: @Dev-iL: I’ve seen interactive plots where the line label shows up when hovering over the line, and a pull-down menu allows to select the line for a specific case. Listing all case names in a huge list just removes space useful for the plotted data. It’s like an index: it’s printed as a long list in a book, but no website or other digital document has one, there are better ways to search within the document when it’s digital.

Comment: @Dev-iL: StackOverflow limits search results to 50 entries per page. Coincidence? :D

Comment: @CrisLuengo I know exactly what you mean. I merely pointed out that some people are used to working like I mentioned, even though there might be a better way to present the same data (there usually is). As for the results per page, I bet one can play with the API to get a different number :þ

Answer (score 3):

As implied by Cris's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58274008/displaying-more-than-50-variables-in-matlab-legend#comment102917615_58274008), it's likely that your plot is going to be very unclear - if you need 50+ legend entries then you've got 50+ different line styles, which is pretty crazy from a usability perspective.

That aside, you can achieve an unrestricted legend using the `gridLegend` [FileExchange submission](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29248-gridlegend-a-multi-column-format-for-legends).

```
% Plot some dummy data, 60 series with various markers / lines
ms = {'*','+','.','d','s','o'};
ls = {'--','-',':','-.'};
x = linspace( 0, 10, 100 ).';
figure(); hold on;
for ii = 1:60;
    y = sin(x+ii) + ii + rand(100,1)/2;
    p(ii) = plot( x, y, ms{randi(6)}, 'linestyle', ls{randi(4)} );
end
% Call the legend
gridLegend( p );
```

Output:

[image: plot]

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem myself and found an undocumented feature that can help—the `'LimitMaxLegendEntries'` property of Legend (`'matlab.graphics.illustration.Legend'`) objects. Here's an example:

```matlab
hF = figure(); 
hAx = axes(hF);
plot(hAx, magic(100));
hL = legend(hAx, '-DynamicLegend');
set(hL, 'LimitMaxLegendEntries', false, 'NumColumns', 3);
```

Which results in:

[image]

Tested on R2020a.

P.S.
While I agree that these likely way too many legend entries to be useful, I believe one should have the freedom to shoot themselves in the foot.

Comment: Interesting this works on 2020a, wonder when it was introduced

Comment: @Wolfie Just tested it on R2018a, and `There is no LimitMaxLegendEntries property on the Legend class.`.

Comment: Cool, but it does not seem to work for me if typing:
figure; plot(randn(100,100)); matlab.graphics.illustration.Legend.LimitMaxLegendEntries = 100; legend

Answer (score 1):

A [solution](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/362378#answer_570629) suggested by [Eric Sargent](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/profile/authors/12010449) (TMW Staff) is to pass the plot handles to the `legend` command:

```matlab
p = plot(magic(100));
legend(p);
```

Note that in this case, the axes are not determined by `gca`, but instead using `ancestor(p, 'axes')` (so there's no need to specify the axes handle when calling `legend`). Moreover, specifying an axes handle makes this solution [stop working](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/362378#comment_1225792)!